# Skype API - to make calls and send messages

Tags: c#, skype, skypedeveloper, skype4com

Is there a way to implement skype API in C# or any other language.

I was using Skype4com.DLL but it is deprecated not working with the skype latest updates. I was using it in a Skype plugin(windows application) to log in and make calls. As an alternative, I thought UCWA Skype Web SDK would be the best solution, but it serves a different purpose.

There are companies that are still using it like https://www.minutizer.com/. I can't figure out the way they are able to detect calls and messages.

Help needed! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to: [Skype Developer Platform supported topologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform) you can choose from:

[image]

You can also choose to use [Lync SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/code-samples-lync-sdk) -

> By using Lync 2013, a developer can provide instant messaging (IM),
>   voice, video, application sharing, and meeting session functionality
>   in a custom client or LOB application

Answer (score 0):

Skype has discontinued the desktop API in 2013. As a result, you wouldn't find any libraries supporting skype programmatically. That's the reason for deprecating libraries like **Skype4com** and **Skype4Java**.

https://blogs.skype.com/news/2013/11/06/feature-evolution-and-support-for-the-skype-desktop-api/

The best option for you to implement voice, SMS or video calling is to use a service like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) or [Plivo](https://www.plivo.com/) which are having wide support for many programming languages including C#.

Comment: Read the question again pls. there are products that are still using skype for the same purpose as mentioned. I want to know the way they are able to achieve it.

Comment: @devedv Minutizer is just tracking calls and SMS of particular Skype account. Its not used for making calls or SMS. Check their site https://www.minutizer.com/how-it-works/#tab-id-2

Comment: @DinushaNT how can we track messages of a particular skype messages? I'm taking about skype for desktop i.e. Skype Personal and not skype for business or lync