# API skype support C# mvc5 in 2021 (not skype for business)

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5, skype, sendmessage

Example:  When 1 thread(condition: true ) in actionresult in controller
// call function  send 1 message to a account skype
. I search google. Skype only support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_webpages URI. I really don't know  how to complete requirement.

Comment: Please include the codes that you have tried so far. I suggest you to read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting your questions.

Comment: I am sorry. I  don't know  how to use skype api for my example.  Such as : In code C# if(i==5)  // send a message "Ok ".

Comment: In python  it is easy : from skpy import Skype
sk = Skype(username, password) # connect to Skype  .

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59354978/7855321) might be helpful. It seems Skype has officially discontinued some services in regards to desktop API. However, you can still use third-party service providers such as Twilio

Comment: Thanks, very much . It really helpful me .

Comment: @NNT Did you find an api that will work with Skype Personal? I want skype chat conversation in my c# application.