# Send Skype Message using C#

Tags: c#, skype, skypedeveloper

Can someone teach me how to send messages to one person/contact via Skype using the C# application that I made? I just want to make my application send logs via Skype. I already searched Google and all results pointed me to use Skype4Com but it's not working anymore.

Comment: asking for tutorials is off topic here. Here are some official links I found in a 5 seconds search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform , https://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Comment: and here is a SO dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354978/skype-api-to-make-calls-and-send-messages

Answer (score 0):

You can choose [Skype Developer Platform supported topologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform) Lync2013 [LyncSDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/code-samples-lync-sdk) that support chatting through skype

Best

Comment: What about skype personal? What if we want to fetch message from skype personal which is installed on the system to our C# application.