# Is there a .NET Core version of Skype-related operation nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net-core, skype, skypedeveloper

I learned that Skype is a product of Microsoft, but I searched all over Google and couldn't find the latest nuget package that can access the Skype operation of .NET Core.

Does anyone know of such a nuget package? It would be better if there is a sample code, thanks a lot

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Use .NET Core program to send message to Skype group, just like telegram.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make calls using your application, you should try finding an API for Skype.
The only thing i know is that they discontinued their original Api in 2013.
There are thirdparty APIs that would help.
I havent looked up if there are any nuget packages.
[Maybe this will help you a little bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354978/skype-api-to-make-calls-and-send-messages)

Comment: i wanna add that im not that good but i thought that the answer above might help.. 
The Website i linked contains https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/code-samples-lync-sdk
Samples of something called lync-sdk, this could be something that you need, i dont know

Comment: Lync is a different application. It was developed by Microsoft and later rebranded Skype for Business. Skype (confusingly) is separate: it was developed independently and later bought by Microsoft. Skype for Business is more or less completely dead: it was always terrible, and has been almost completely replaced by Teams.